# HTTP POST request results in "ERROR 405: Method Not Allowed"

Tags: http, post, wget

I'm trying to do a simple HTTP POST on the following website:

```
https://oktap.tax.ok.gov/oktap/web/_/
```

(click on "Permits" in the bottom left hand side)

I simply want to post a number and get the results from the page returned.  Looking at the page with chrome's web developer tools it looks like the POST goes to both

```
https://oktap.tax.ok.gov/oktap/web/_/Recalc
https://oktap.tax.ok.gov/oktap/web/_/EventOccurred
```

I'm not sure if it's one or the other, it looks like EventOccured takes a couple more parameters.  However when I post to either one of them with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

wget --post-data="D0IHwpHb__0_0_Ful0QW=5&VIEW__=VS_PermitSearch&LASTFOCUSFIELD__=D0IHwpHb__0_0_Ful0QW&DOC_MODAL_ID__=0&EVENT__=D0IHwpHb__0_0_Ful0QW&DOC_ACTION__=false&TYPE__=1&CLOSECONFIRMED__=false&FAST_VERLAST__=9.CvUZWPROHiWR-EO6d9UAeHYv4m81" \
-U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547 Safari/537.36" \
https://oktap.tax.ok.gov/oktap/web/_/EventOccurred
```

First I get 307 Temporary Redirect and then ERROR 405: Method Not Allowed.

I don't see how the a post is not allowed, when it's clearly being made from the browser just fine.  Any Help?

Here's the headers:

```
Request URL:https://oktap.tax.ok.gov/oktap/web/_/Recalc
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:146
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:wdc-session=w0srLHI6Tz9tDLtEDo0n33PNuXSFexxysEHBa9v5dtjXBt/X4cKb9zKdxoVrtyDKseewwZMbU41vn3DLmyf0QUUjtKwXdmEhHtS69aZf94Y26cqd95rsiCKg06SQVIm5p63me/C2chBBapoABa1lJ8lf4F3MbBIiBAnCnbKlgVfXtsjpijt9i2PMILjlAalr
Host:oktap.tax.ok.gov
Origin:https://oktap.tax.ok.gov
Referer:https://oktap.tax.ok.gov/oktap/web/_/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/31.0.1650.4 Chrome/31.0.1650.4 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
D0IHwpHb__0_0_Ful0QW:5
VIEW__:VS_PermitSearch
LASTFOCUSFIELD__:D0IHwpHb__0_0_Ful0QW
DOC_MODAL_ID__:0
FAST_VERLAST__:3.2sMmdbnwgvAQF41H3c_2XHozyeA1
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en, en-US
Content-Length:318
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 03 Oct 2013 19:52:52 GMT
Expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Set-Cookie:wdc-session=w0srLHI6Tz9tDLtEDo0n33PNuXSFexxysEHBa9v5dtjXBt/X4cKb9zKdxoVrtyDKseewwZMbU41vn3DLmyf0QUUjtKwXdmEhHtS69aZf94Y26cqd95rsiCKg06SQVIm5p63me/C2chBBapoABa1lJ8lf4F3MbBIiBAnCnbKlgVfXtsjpijt9i2PMILjlAalr; path=/oktap/web/; HttpOnly; Secure;
X-Frame-Options:DENY
```

and

```
Request URL:https://oktap.tax.ok.gov/oktap/web/_/EventOccurred
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:226
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:wdc-session=w0srLHI6Tz9tDLtEDo0n33PNuXSFexxysEHBa9v5dtjXBt/X4cKb9zKdxoVrtyDKseewwZMbU41vn3DLmyf0QUUjtKwXdmEhHtS69aZf94Y26cqd95rsiCKg06SQVIm5p63me/C2chBBapoABa1lJ8lf4F3MbBIiBAnCnbKlgVfXtsjpijt9i2PMILjlAalr
Host:oktap.tax.ok.gov
Origin:https://oktap.tax.ok.gov
Referer:https://oktap.tax.ok.gov/oktap/web/_/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/31.0.1650.4 Chrome/31.0.1650.4 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
D0IHwpHb__0_0_Ful0QW:5
VIEW__:VS_PermitSearch
LASTFOCUSFIELD__:D0IHwpHb__0_0_Ful0QW
DOC_MODAL_ID__:0
EVENT__:D0IHwpHb__0_0_Ful0QW
DOC_ACTION__:false
TYPE__:1
CLOSECONFIRMED__:false
FAST_VERLAST__:4.Ol_i_B9mDsWsP0Mg0e02_y7OZjM1
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en, en-US
Content-Length:3711
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 03 Oct 2013 19:52:52 GMT
Expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Set-Cookie:wdc-session=w0srLHI6Tz9tDLtEDo0n33PNuXSFexxysEHBa9v5dtjXBt/X4cKb9zKdxoVrtyDKseewwZMbU41vn3DLmyf0QUUjtKwXdmEhHtS69aZf94Y26cqd95rsiCKg06SQVIm5p63me/C2chBBapoABa1lJ8lf4F3MbBIiBAnCnbKlgVfXtsjpijt9i2PMILjlAalr; path=/oktap/web/; HttpOnly; Secure;
X-Frame-Options:DENY
```

Comment: It will be hard to give you a direct answer, and the details will depend on the implementation of the site you are trying to trigger.  It may be that they are looking for something very specific, like a session id or some auth key in the headers.  It seems like they were trying to prevent people from using the call outside of their site.  I would start by opening up Chrome, doing the calls from the site like normal, and paying VERY close attention to what you see going on in the headers.  Then try to mimic those actions.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer for that company, I would not recommend looking up permits that way. For $150 per year you can get a file with this information.

Contact the OTC. http://www.tax.ok.gov/rules/rule6507.pdf - 710:65-9-6. Subscription to sales tax permit list

Comment: Is it also possible to get a subscription to a list for Colorado permits?  I figure you would know since your company also works on their site?  https://www.colorado.gov/revenueonline/_/#1

Comment: I would imagine so, but I'm not familiar with their rules. Your best bet is to contact the Department of Revenue.